# Postgres Histogram Adding Records

Tags: postgresql, histogram, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression, window-functions

Creating histogram using Postgres 15, getting strange results.

My column has 25 records, depending on the `nbins` value in the `bin_params` cte I get different record counts when I sum the `'freq'` column.  When `nbins` = 12 or 13 I get too many (26).  When `nbins` = 11 I get the right count of 25.

Another approached I've tried, but led to similarly confusing results, is to multiply the `min(x)` in the `bin_params` cte by .99, .999, and .9999999.  When I vary the # of decimal places I get differing record counts returned, same behavior as described above.

My desired solution is `sum(freq)` = # or records in the column.

I've read/tried solutions from [here](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2014/02/postgresql-aggregates-and-histograms/), [here](https://ubiq.co/database-blog/create-histogram-postgresql/) and [here](https://www.timescale.com/forum/t/how-to-create-a-histogram-within-your-database/134), along with many others.  The code below is as close as I've come to a workable solution.

Thank you for helping me.

Here's my code (sample data at the bottom):

```
with rnorm as
                (SELECT 
                        my_col::numeric as x
                        from my_table
                ),
bin_params as
                (select 
                        min(x) as min_x 
                        ,max(x) as max_x
                        ,13 as nbins
                from rnorm),
temp_bins as
                (SELECT
                        generate_series(min_x::numeric, max_x::numeric, ((max_x - min_x) / nbins)::numeric) as bin
                from bin_params
                ),
bin_range as
                ( select
                        lag(bin) over (order by bin) as low_bin
                        ,b.bin as high_bin

                    from temp_bins b
                ),
frequency_table as
        (   select
                        b.low_bin
                        ,b.high_bin
                        ,count(*) as freq
                from bin_range b
                left join rnorm r
                        on r.x <= b.high_bin
                        and r.x > b.low_bin
                where   b.low_bin is not null
                        and b.high_bin is not null
                group by
                        b.low_bin
                        ,b.high_bin
                        ,count_x
                order by b.low_bin
        )

select * from frequency_table
```

my_table:

```
|"my_col"|
|------|
|74.03|
|73.995|
|73.988|
|74.002|
|73.992|
|74.009|
|73.995|
|73.985|
|74.008|
|73.998|
|73.994|
|74.004|
|73.983|
|74.006|
|74.012|
|74|
|73.994|
|74.006|
|73.984|
|74|
|73.988|
|74.004|
|74.01|
|74.015|
|73.982|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three issues.

First, `generate_series()` results may not contain the `stop` value, it depends on the step. See the third example in [Set Returning Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html). You can add `step` to the second parameter to be sure that all values are in the generated ranges.

Second, the strict inequality `r.x > b.low_bin` omits `min_x` value. Use a bit smaller `start` parameter for generated series.

Third, `count(*) as freq` gives 1 even when there are no values in the range (because of left join). Should be `count(x) as freq`.

Comment: 2nd & 3rd suggestion are clear, thank you.  
First one I'm not following --> posted code is `generate_series(min_x::numeric, max_x::numeric, ((max_x - min_x) / nbins)::numeric)` which follows `generate_series ( start numeric, stop numeric [, step numeric ] )` example you are pointing to, isn't it?  Made 2nd & 3rd suggestions in code, but when I change # of bins the `sum(freq)` still doesn't add up. 
Thank you for clarifying, it really helps.

Comment: I meant the third example in the code block below. See [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/u3PGZsK6)

Comment: Still stuck - per explanation & strict `r.x > b.low_bin` I modified to `start numeric` param to capture the `min(x)` value, but at `nbins`=12 I get correct record count, `nbins` = 13 and I'm one short.  Here's current line of code:
`generate_series(min_x - (((max_x - min_x) / nbins) ::numeric, max_x::numeric, ((max_x - min_x) / nbins)::numeric) as bin`  I believe I'm following most of the logic you're suggesting, but can't figure out why record counts would fluctuate after changes suggested made.

Comment: You should correct `stop`. Test my query: [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/MDvbwref)

Comment: Inspired by your feedback I ended up here:
`generate_series(min_x - (step/2.0) , max_x + (step/2.0), step)` - appreciate your insight to solve this - thank you.